# get an image data from web service with firemonkey

Tags: delphi

My question is, we have a database and web service so we are trying to fetch a image from database with web service. We are keeping our image as image on database and we are trying to fetch it as a binary array. Its completly reducing its space and we could't fetch the image we just have little kind of numbers. What do we really need to do  ? Thanks for all answer.

```
try 
  LOutputStream := TMemoryStream.Create; 
  TBlobField(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('resimx')).SaveToStream(LOutputStream); 
  LOutputStream.Position:=0; 
  AlarmImage.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(LOutputStream); 
finally 
  LOutputStream.Free; 
end;
```

Comment: Please add your code and clarify your problem. It is unclear what are you asking. Also visit [help] to read more about this site and asking questions here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use some encode (Base64 by example) to send the image.

See this samples:

- ["Binary to Base64 (Delphi)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795263/binary-to-base64-delphi)
- ["Decode Base64 encoded image from XML doc"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644745/delphi-2010-decode-base64-encoded-image-from-xml-doc)

Regards.